# Unsubscribe Event Handler from Protected Override Void

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to unsubscribe an event handler from an protected override void?

```
 protected override void OnViewLoaded(object sender, ViewLoadedEventArg e)
    {
        base.OnViewLoaded(sender, e);
        list = VisualTreeUtil.FindFirstInTree<ListView>(Application.Current.MainWindow, "ListView");
        ConfigureAndSuperviseInputControls(this.list);
        ScrollViewer scroll = VisualTreeUtil.FindFirstInTree<ScrollViewer>(this.list);
        scroll.ScrollChanged+=new ScrollChangedEventHandler(scroll_ScrollChanged);       
    }

  void scroll_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {  
        ConfigureAndSuperviseInputControls(this.list);
        ScrollViewer sb = e.OriginalSource as ScrollViewer;
        if (sb.ContentVerticalOffset==sb.ScrollableHeight)
        {
           scroll.ScrollChanged-=new ScrollChangedEventHandler(scroll_ScrollChanged); 
        }
    }
```

My problem is that i dont get acces to the scroll obejct in the scroll_ScrollChanged Method.

Comment: Isn't sender a reference to the object that you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is not tested but can't you simple cast the sender object to the ScrollViewer and unsubscribe from the event like that:

```
protected override void OnViewLoaded(object sender, ViewLoadedEventArg e)
    {
        base.OnViewLoaded(sender, e);
        list = VisualTreeUtil.FindFirstInTree<ListView>(Application.Current.MainWindow, "ListView");
        ConfigureAndSuperviseInputControls(this.list);
        ScrollViewer scroll = VisualTreeUtil.FindFirstInTree<ScrollViewer>(this.list);
        scroll.ScrollChanged+=new ScrollChangedEventHandler(scroll_ScrollChanged);       
    }

  void scroll_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {  
        ConfigureAndSuperviseInputControls(this.list);
        ScrollViewer scroll = (ScrollViewer)sender;
        if (scroll.ContentVerticalOffset==scroll.ScrollableHeight)
        {
           scroll.ScrollChanged-=new ScrollChangedEventHandler(scroll_ScrollChanged); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sender should be a reference to the object that you require.

```
protected override void OnViewLoaded(object sender, ViewLoadedEventArg e)
    {
        base.OnViewLoaded(sender, e);
        list = VisualTreeUtil.FindFirstInTree<ListView>(Application.Current.MainWindow, "ListView");
        ConfigureAndSuperviseInputControls(this.list);
        ScrollViewer scroll = VisualTreeUtil.FindFirstInTree<ScrollViewer>(this.list);
        scroll.ScrollChanged+=new ScrollChangedEventHandler(scroll_ScrollChanged);       
    }

  void scroll_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {  
        ConfigureAndSuperviseInputControls(this.list);
        ScrollViewer sb = sender as ScrollViewer;
        if (sb.ContentVerticalOffset==sb.ScrollableHeight)
        {
           scroll.ScrollChanged-=new ScrollChangedEventHandler(scroll_ScrollChanged); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems it took me too long to write my answer ;)

Comment: Nothing changed with sender as reference

Comment: Breakpoint the line  "if (sb.ContentVerticalOffset==sb.ScrollableHeight)" and see if sender has a reference to a ScrollViewer

Comment: Sender has an reference to scrollviewer but scroll is unknown in  scroll_ScrollChanged Method. ScrollViewer scroll = (ScrollViewer)sender did it.

Comment: Oh I see, I left in the scroll reference instead of setting to sb, well you have your answer :)